# intel xeon windows 10 fan speed so high and noise

Tags: cpu, intel, hardware, noise

After installing windows 10 pro on my Xeon workstation, i realize the case's fan speed up so quickly since sign on desktop, and it's very noise.

Not open any application and wait for speed down.

The fan speed is still at very high and of course noise, and CPU temp 's always around 60C-68C

Does anyone have a recommendation ? it didn't happen on windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few googles and somewhere they said it might be a problem with Power settings on windows.

I tried to fix my settings: **Start** > **Power & Sleep settings** > **Additional power settings** > choose **Balanced**

[image]

And the fan speed goes down, and better noise, especially the CPU temp goes down to ~ 40C if not open the heavy things (just got Chrome at the moment)

[image]

I'm happy with this result. Just want to share you guys for the case.

You can also customize the **Balanced** settings to make your optimistic